# Как дождаться завершения функции что б запустить следующую?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как дождаться завершения функции fetchData() что б запустить следующую fetchForecastData()?
нужны данные lon i lat с fetchData что бы использовать их в fetchForecastData(). Если в код добавить функцию fetchForecastData() когда  fetchData() уже прогрузилась все работает но после перезагрузки все улетает , помогите пожалуйста

````
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
  const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState([]);
  const [weatherForecast, setWeatherForecast] = useState([]);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState('');
  const [lon, setLon] = useState('');

  const addSearchCity = (search) => {
    setLocation(search);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid={API}&units=metric`,
    );
    setCurrentWeather(res.data);
    setLat(res.data.coord.lat);
    setLon(res.data.coord.lon);
  };
  const fetchForecastData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid={API}&units=metric`,
    );
    setWeatherForecast(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchForecastData();
  }, []);

  console.log(currentWeather);
  console.log(weatherForecast);
  console.log(lat, lon);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Search addSearchCity={addSearchCity} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home currentWeather={currentWeather} lat={lat} lon={lon} />} />
        <Route path="/week" element={<Forecast currentWeather={currentWeather} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App; ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай одну асинхронную функцию и внутрь помести два await первого запроса и второго

```js
const fetchAllData = async () => {
    const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid={API}&units=metric`,);
    setCurrentWeather(res.data);
    const result = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${res.data.coord.lat}&lon=${res.data.coord.lon}&appid={API}&units=metric`,);
    setWeatherForecast(result);
}
```